# How to proof $X/G\times X/G\cong (X\times X)/(G\times G)$ for scheme X and finite subgroup scheme $G\subset X$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties, group-schemes

Sorry  for my bad English.

I'm having some trouble understanding the claim in Mumford's "Abelian Varieties" p.111.

Let $k$ be algebraically closed field,  $X$ be group scheme over $k$, and $G\subset X$ be a finite subgroup scheme.

In this book, he says  $X/G\times X/G\cong (X\times X)/(G\times G)$ as scheme.

Now we have natural map $(X\times X)/(G\times G)\to X/G\times X/G$ by universal property of the product or by  $G\times G$-invariant of $X\times X\to  X/G\times X/G$.

But I don't know how to construct $X/G\times X/G\to (X\times X)/(G\times G)$, so that I don't know how to prove $X/G\times X/G\cong (X\times X)/(G\times G)$.

Please tell me proof or hint, thanks.

Comment: If $G$ is a finite group acting on a $k$-algebra $A$ (let for simplicity $k$ be a field). Is there a relation between $A^G \otimes_k A^G$ and $(A\otimes_k A)^{G\times G}$? Ask yourself the question: When are these $k$-algebras isomorphic?

Comment: Note: there is a canonical map  $\phi:A^G\otimes_k A^G \rightarrow (A\otimes_k A)^{G\times G}$ and the first question you should ask yourself is: When is $\phi$ an isomorphism? You should try to answer this question before you  begin to speak about "category theory".

Comment: @hm2020 I try to prove $\phi$ is ring isomorphism, but I failed it because element of tensor product is hard to handle.

Comment: **Question:** "I try to prove $ϕ$ is ring isomorphism, but I failed it because element of tensor product is hard to handle. – Ryu"

**Answer:** If $char (k) \neq  \# G:=l$ there is an operator $R(x):=1/l \sum_{g \in G} gx$ - the Reynolds operator. Maybe this operator can be helpful. Using it you may prove that $G$ is "linearly reductive" in the sense of
"A. Bialynicki-Birula, Quotients by actions of groups, Encyclopediq Math. Sci. 131, Springer Verlag (2002)"

Comment: From 7.1.7 in BB it follows that if $H \subseteq G$ is a normal subgroup and if $G\times X \rightarrow X$ is an action then there is an isomorphism

$$F1.\text{   }(X/H)/(G/H) \cong X/G.$$

In your case you take $H:=G\times \{e\} \subseteq G\times G$ as a normal subgroup. Let $X:=Spec(A\otimes_k A)$. You get isomorphisms

$$Spec((A\otimes_k A)^{G\times G}) :=X/G \cong (X/H)/(G/H) \cong$$

 $$Spec((A^G)\otimes_k A)/(\{e\}\times G) \cong Spec(A^G \otimes_k A^G).$$

Comment: You could also try to understand what the "Reynolds operator" is in terms of the dual action. If $\tilde{G}:=Spec(R)$ is the constant group scheme of $G$, there is a dual action 

$$\sigma_G: A \rightarrow A\otimes_k R$$

Any you may define the invariants $A^G$ using $\sigma_G$. Then you may try to prove $F1$ using $\sigma_G$ and $R$.

Comment: PS: the result in BB proves formula $F1$ in greater generality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give a map $$X/G\times X/G\to X\times X/(G\times G)$$ we need to give for a scheme $S$ over $k$, the map $$X/G\times X/G(S)\to X\times X/(G\times G)(S)$$ i.e.
$$X/G(S)\times X/G(S)\to X\times X/(G\times G)(S).$$

Let $a, b:S\to X/G$. There is an fppf-cover of $S'\to S$ of $S$ such that $a$ and $b$ lift to $a', b': S'\to X$.

The lifts $a', b': S'\to X$ are so that $S'\to S\xrightarrow{a} X/G$ agrees with $S'\xrightarrow{a'} X \to X/G$ and similarly for $b'.$

Now $a'\times b': S'\to X\times X$.

Consider $$a'\times b': S' \xrightarrow{a'\times b'} X\times X\to X\times X/(G\times G).$$

We observe by the fppf-descent that the morphism $a'\times b'$ descents to $S\to  X\times X/(G\times G)$ which we denote by $a\times b$.

Observe that this is well defined i.e. does not depend on the lifts $a'$ and $b'$ of $a$ and $b$ respectvely.

Comment: Can we take such $a’$？